# Can't get Active Directory User using Distinguished Name with group

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have the following Distinguished Name to find a user in my Active Directory: `CN=ronaldo.lanhellas,OU=SERVICOS_EXTERNOS,OU=Departamento de TI,OU=Record Belem,DC=recordbelem,DC=com,DC=br`

This works fine, but I created a GROUP called CEDOC2 and I put the user "ronaldo.lanhellas" inside this group, see:

[image: Group CEDOC2]

Now I'm trying to access the user ronaldo.lanhellas inside this group, with this DN:

`CN=ronaldo.lanhellas,CN=CEDOC2,OU=_Sistemas,DC=recordbelem,DC=com,DC=br` but i got **"Invalid Credentials"**

Comment: Doesn't you intent was to create an OU instead of a CN?

[Object Naming](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977992.aspx)

Comment: A user can be part only one OU, and i can't move the actual user from your OU. So, i created a GROUP and putted all users in this group, so only users in this GROUP can access my SYSTEM.

Comment: So, how can i create a OU=CEDOC2 and reference users in another OU ? Remember, i can't move the users from your original OU.

Comment: AD/LDAP don't work like this. The dn `CN=ronaldo.lanhellas,CN=CEDOC2,OU=_Siste...` does not exist, you can see there is no such entry in the scope pane. Don't confuse a group membership and the position of an entry in the DIT (functional vs structural). If `CN=CEDOC2` is a group, you can have a sub group `CN=SUBCEDOC2,CN=CEDOC2` in the DIT but a user wouldn't make sense here. Membership is maintained via `member` and `memberOf` attributes.

Comment: Your user DN will stay the same unless you move the entry in another ou. It is not clear what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I Just want to know If exist some way to solve It without move user to another OU. I need group a list of users from diferent OU into only one place that can be accesed by DN

Comment: What you've done to with user ronaldo.lanhellas is ok, you can 'group a list of users from diferent OU' as well, just use the dn of the group and fetch the member attribute to get the list of members. If you want to restrict the members from read operations for example you should deal with access control (ACE/ACL).